# regular expression for the following expression in java

Tags: java, regex

What can be the regular expression (java) for the expressions of following patterns:

```
currency-symbol=digit(min length=0, max length=4).(optional)digit(min length=0, max length=4)
```

For example:

```
eur=1

gbp=3.2

usd=40.05

AUD=0.33
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[a-zA-Z]{3}=\d{0,4}([.]\d{0,4})?
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]{3}=\\d{0,4}(\\.\\d{0,4})?$");
```